# How did he went from $b_{12}$ to $\tan 2\varphi=\cfrac{2a_{12}}{a_{11}-a_{22}}$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm reading Aarts': *Plane and Solid Geometry*. Here:

> [image]

How did he go from $b_{12}$ to $\tan 2\varphi=\cfrac{2a_{12}}{a_{11}-a_{22}}$? I have tried a few things on paper but I throw it all away because there was no progress, but I basically used the formulas for double angles and $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. I've even speculated that one must be high to understand it. The tag of the formula is [$(4.20)$, perhaps this is no coincidence](https://youtu.be/KOLa22n5i3o) but I smoked some joints and nothing happened.

Comment: I would say, $b_{12}=0 \Rightarrow \tan 2\varphi = \cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have: $$b_{12} = -\frac{1}{2}a_{11}\sin 2\varphi + a_{12}\cos 2\varphi + \frac{1}{2}a_{22}\sin 2\varphi.$$

Division by $\cos 2\varphi$ gives: $$b_{12}\frac{1}{\cos 2\varphi} = -\frac{1}{2}a_{11}\tan 2\varphi + a_{12} + \frac{1}{2}a_{22}\tan 2\varphi.$$ From here: $$\tan 2\varphi =  \frac{2\left(a_{12} - \frac{b_{12}}{\cos 2\varphi}  \right)}{a_{11} - a_{22}}.$$ Surely you're not too high to conclude now?